# Short story published in Sci-Fi Best in 60's-70's about delivering a unique animal to home planet or keep in captivity

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

the short Sci-Fi story I'm looking for I read many years ago, is about a spacecraft captain who is suppose to deliver alien species held in the spacecraft to some sort of zoo. One particular being is dying in captivity, and the captain decides to let it go on to its home planet which is a highly dangerous environment to give it a chance to live. The story is about his decision to let it go, which is how the story ends.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You suggest you might have read this in a year's best collection; do you have any idea which?  Merril's?  Wollheim's?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't. My best guess was the yearly Sci-Fi Anthology best short stories, I read a lot of them back then.

Comment: How did the decision go? You can put it under a spoiler quote ">!” if you like.

Comment: @rjmoran Looks like that markdown doesn't work for comments. You might want to edit your post to add the spoiler, and delete the comment.

Comment: okay, how would I do that?

Answer (score 4):

Could this be "[Novice](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55488)" by [James Schmitz](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?394) (read for free at [Project Gutenberg](https://gutenberg.org/cache/epub/30458/pg30458-images.html))?

In this short novel, the protagonist Telzey Amberdon, has a pet Baluit Crest Cat, which is a species of animal known only from one planet so far.

> Dr. Droon steepled his fingers. "Well," he said, "she ... your pet ... is, ah, a young crest cat. Nearly full grown now, apparently, and—"...
>
> ...The zoologist and Halet exchanged glances. Then Dr. Droon resumed cautiously. The crest cats, he said, were a species native to Jontarou. Their existence had been known for only eight years. The species appeared to have had a somewhat limited range—the Baluit mountains on the opposite side of the huge continent on which Port Nichay had been built....

This species has been classified as extremely dangerous, but is able to be hunted using specialist equipment. Despite this, the hunters and cats seem to have a 1:1 kill ratio - one hunter killed for every cat, making them highly prized for hunters.

> The rules, Dr. Droon explained, laid down the type of equipment ... weapons, spotting and tracking instruments, number of assistants, and so forth ... a sportsman could legitimately use in the pursuit of any specific type of game. "Before the end of the first year after their discovery," he went on, "the Baluit crest cats had been placed in the ultra-equipment class."
>
> "What's ultra-equipment?" Telzey asked.
>
> "Well," Dr. Droon said thoughtfully, "it doesn't quite involve the use of full battle armor ... not quite! And, of course, even with that classification the sporting principle of mutual accessibility must be observed."
>
> "Mutual ... oh, I see!" Telzey paused as another wave of silent information rose into her awareness; went on, "So the game has to be able to get at the sportsman too, eh?"
>
> "That's correct. Except in the pursuit of various classes of flying animals, a shikari would not, for example, be permitted the use of an aircar other than as means of simple transportation. Under these conditions, it was soon established that crest cats were being obtained by sportsmen who went after them at a rather consistent one-to-one ration."
>
> Telzey's eyes widened. She'd gathered something similar from her other information source but hadn't quite believed it. "One hunter killed for each cat bagged?" she said. "That's pretty rough sport, isn't it?...
>
> ... He shook his head. "Two immature male specimens are know to exist, and they are at present in the Life Banks. The others that were taken alive at the time have been destroyed ... often under nearly disastrous circumstances. They are enormously cunning, enormously savage creatures, Miss Amberdon! The additional fact that they can conceal themselves to the point of being virtually indetectable except by the use of instruments makes them one of the most dangerous animals known.

During this exchange it is revealed that no-one has seen a Crest cat for a couple of years and they were thought to be extinct:

> "And then a curious thing happened. Less than two years after their existence became known, the crest cats of the Baluit range were extinct! The inroads made on their numbers by man cannot begin to account for this, so it must be assumed that a sudden plague wiped them out. At any rate, not another living member of the species has been seen on Jontarou until you landed here with your pet last night."

Basically, Dr Droon wants to take Telzey's Cat for the "Life Banks" to preserve the species, as the other captured ones have had to be put down. Telzey then establishes telepathic contact with her Cat, who reveals a whole bunch of Cats living in amongst the humans, just camouflaged, who are waiting to take over and eliminate the humans on their planet. Telzey intervenes and reveals her contact with them and that they are likely sentient, saving both the Cats and the Humans. Her Cat, having been off-planet for some time, disappears into the wilds to experience life as a wild cat again.

Matches:

- rare species
- Few in captivity
- Animal being released
- Home planet

Mis-matches:

- Not captain releasing
- Not released from space-ship
- Planet is not dangerous, only hunting making it dangerous